# is it possible to make multiple rtsp videocapture in one control?

Tags: c#, video-streaming, rtsp, emgucv

I'm try to make RTSP Player for 36 channel with C#.
Each channel capture rtsp (640x480, 20fps).
However this RTSP Player consume high CPU.
I want high performance but it's not.
About 60% Cpu Usage while capture.
I want know it's mediocre performance or abnormal performance.
I'm using Opencv(emgu.cv) without GPU, my Computer using Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9700F CPU @ 3.00GHz   3.00 GHz.

Please help me how to capture 36 rtsp channel with nice performance.

Thank you.

Comment: capture is cheap. just store the stream data. your mistake is probably that you also decode the streams. that happens because you use a library for computer vision. it's not for wrangling media streams, it's for computer vision. it works under different assumptions, such as: sources will always be decoded. use a different library.

Comment: your comment means change library for capture only without decoding? not emgu.cv(openCv)??

Comment: if i have to change, can you recommend any nuget package?

Comment: If U want to Display Them U need to decode Them